# Dropout backpropagation implementation details

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, dropout

Just to summarize 
[Understanding dropout and gradient descent](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6921/understanding-dropout-and-gradient-descent)
and
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207481/dropout-backpropagation-implementation

Suppose I need to implement **inverted dropout** in my CNN. All the neuron outputs in dropout layer during feedforward phase are multiplied by mask/p, where mask is 0 or 1, p is retain rate. But should I apply the same operation (include **division by p**) at the backpropagation phase? I suppose positive answer (see the second link above), but I need to know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

As given in the links, the answer is yes! note that you divide the mask by p so that you won't need to multiply by p in the test time and since this is a coefficient for the new activation, it will come out of the derivative in chain rule in backprop.